# How to show timer in specific format?

Tags: android, timer, format

I know here is lot of question on "start/stop timer".But i am looking for format of
timer.  I am developing one recording application which show record time.
I able to show time in second format like 1 2 3 4 5. but i need to show this time like
**00.01**. I need some hint or reference.  here is image which i need to show.  [image]
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/simple-countdowntimer-example/) is the very nice tutorial of simple countdown timer. Go through it and you will be able to achieve what you want.

Or [A Stitch in Time](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html) is the efficient way to implement the stop watch type app from developer.android.com and yes it uses the format you required.

Comment: i already tried this but it show all second. but i need to show minute.second format...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
private String stringForTime(int timeMs) {
    StringBuilder mFormatBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    Formatter mFormatter = new Formatter(mFormatBuilder, Locale.getDefault());

    int totalSeconds = timeMs / 1000;

    int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
    int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
    int hours   = totalSeconds / 3600;

    mFormatBuilder.setLength(0);
    if (hours > 0) {
        return mFormatter.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds).toString();
    } else {
        return mFormatter.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds).toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: but actually i need to start timer on start button and stop timer on stop button. i didn't provide time to timer. therefore it's not possible to covert like your code. thank you